# Isomorphic Embeddings in Model Theory

Tags: logic, model-theory

I have been working through an assortment of problems in logic and model theory to solidify my own understanding of the subject before the upcoming school year and I am unsure on some of the details of a particular problem. The exercise in question is number 1.3.2 from Chang & Keisler. Here is a copy of the problem:

A model  is isomorphically embedded in  if there is a model ℭ and an isomorphism  such that :≃ℭ and ℭ⊂. The subset symbol in this context refers to a submodel

Let $\mathfrak{A}\overset{\sim}{\subset} \mathfrak{B}$ mean that $\mathfrak{A}$ is isomorphically embedded in $\mathfrak{B}$. Show that the relation $\overset{\sim}{\subset}$ is reflexive, transitive but not antisymmetric. Let $N$ be the set of all natural number $\{0,1,2,...\}$. Decide if the following are true or false

1. $\langle N,\leq, +,0\rangle \overset{\sim}{\subset}\langle N,\leq, *,1\rangle$
2. $\langle N,\leq, *,1\rangle \overset{\sim}{\subset}\langle N,\leq, +,0\rangle$
3. $\langle N-\{0\},\leq, *,1\rangle \overset{\sim}{\subset}\langle N,\leq, +,0\rangle$
4. $\langle N-\{0\}, *,1\rangle \overset{\sim}{\subset}\langle N, +,0\rangle$
5. $\langle N-\{0\}, *\rangle \overset{\sim}{\subset}\langle N, +\rangle$

So I have shown the relation to be reflexive and transitive but have failed to show its not antisymmetric. I understand that since it is $\textit{not}$ antisymmetric that it is possible to have $A\overset{\sim}{\subset}B$ and $B\overset{\sim}{\subset}A$ while $A\neq B$ but I do not know which examples of the ones given fufill this. Also when I attempted to prove 1 true or false I tried to use the map of taking addition to multiplication by sending the number $k \rightarrow 2^k$ but I am not sure if this is the correct way to proceed or how to reverse the process for multiplication to addition. I am also not sure how to show that no such map exists if that is the case.

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of "$\mathfrak A$ is isomorphically embedded in $\mathfrak B$", and what is the definition of $\mathfrak A=\mathfrak B$? It would be quite easy to give an example of two nonisomorphic structures such that each is isomorphic to a substructure of the other,, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're asking. Are you sure the word is "embedded" and not "embeddable"?

Comment: $\Bbb B=<N,*,\le,1>$ is not isomorphic to any sub-structure of $\Bbb A=<N,+,\le,0>$ because $\Bbb B$ satisfies the sentence $\exists x\,\forall y\,(x*y=x) ,$ ... But if $C\subset N$ and  $\exists u\in C\,\forall v\in C\,(u+v=u)$ then $C=\{0\}, $ and $\Bbb B$ also satisfies $\exists w,z\, (w\ne z).$... BTW for any $k\in N$ with $k>1$ the map $f(n)=k^n$ embeds $\Bbb A$ into $\Bbb B. $ Think of $\Bbb A$ as logarithms to base $k$.

Comment: Here are the definitions I forgot to include: 
A model $\mathfrak{A}$ is  isomorphically embedded in $\mathfrak{B}$ if there is a model $\mathfrak{C}$ and an isomorphism $f$ such that $f:\mathfrak{A}\simeq \mathfrak{C}$ and $\mathfrak{C}\subset \mathfrak{B}$. The subset symbol in this context refers to a submodel.

Comment: @bof I think that "an example of two non isomorphic structures such that each is isomorphic to a substructure of the other" would serve to show that this relationship is not antisymmetric since I believe  $\mathfrak A=\mathfrak B$ to mean isomorphic models

Comment: @ConnorLockhart Each of the ordered sets $\langle(0,1),\le\rangle$ and $\langle[0,1],\le\rangle$ is isomorphic to a substructure of the other, and they are not isomorphic or even elementarily equivalent. If you want countable madels, use $(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q$ and $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$.